# How can we use Kotlin object with Java controllers?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin and I read that it is compatible with Java.

Can I define all of my classes in Kotlin and instantiate them in a Java controller class?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean, but generally yes.  See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) for all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have both Kotlin and Java files in your project, you can refer and create new objects of Kotlin class in Java.

This shows how you can setup such a project in Maven:
https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/maven-java-project